# React js dynamic rendering content not displayed

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am working on Dynamically Rendering content in the component via.Json.But after Rendering content page not displayed .Please help me...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

code pen url: https://codepen.io/dotnet345/pen/oNXBxBM

code sandbox:https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-thompson-t6pf8

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    var files;
    super(props);
    this.state =  {
        selectedFile: null,
        imagePreviewUrl: null,
        Comment:'',
        seen: false,
        showlikePopup: false,
        errors: {},
        likebutton:true,
        savebutton:true,
        count:0,
        clicked: false,
        mypost:[]
      }
      this.onChangeComment = this.onChangeComment.bind(this);
      this.changeColor = this.changeColor.bind(this);
}
onChangeComment(e) {
    this.setState({ Comment: e.target.value })
}
togglePop = () => {
    this.setState({
     seen: !this.state.seen
    });
   };
togglePoplike = () => {
    this.setState({
        showlikePopup: !this.state.showlikePopup
    });
 };
fileChangedHandler = event => {
    this.setState({
        selectedFile: event.target.files[0]
      })
      var file = this.refs.file.files[0].name;
      let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => {
    this.setState({
        imagePreviewUrl: reader.result
    });
    }

     reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0])
}
changeColor= () => {
  this.setState({likebutton: !this.state.likebutton})
  const clicked = this.state.clicked;
  if(clicked){
   this.setState({count: this.state.count - 1, clicked: false});
 } else {
   this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1, clicked: true})
 }
}

viewPost= () =>{
  this.props.history.push('/post')
}

changeColorsave= () => {
  this.setState({savebutton: !this.state.savebutton})
}

handleValidation(){
    let errors = {};
    let formIsValid = true;
    if (this.state.selectedFile == null) {
        formIsValid = false;
        errors["Comment"] = "*Please Select file";
    }
    if(this.state.Comment==""){
        formIsValid = false;
        errors["Comment"] = "*Please enter Caption";
    }
    this.setState({ errors: errors });
    return formIsValid;
}

Submit = (e) => {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', this.state.selectedFile);

    if(this.state.selectedFile!=null){
        const obj = {
            file:this.state.selectedFile.name,
            Comment:this.state.Comment
        }
    }


    if(this.handleValidation()){

    }else{

    }
    e.preventDefault()

}

 render() {   var Json={
     "AllPost":[
        {
           "User_Id":1,
           "Username":"te",
           "Records":[
              {
                 "Profile":[{
                    "User_Id":"1",
                    "UserImage":"",
                    "Fullname":"Test",
                    "Username":"te"
                 }],
                 "Post":[{
                    "Post_Id":"1",
                    "UploadFile":"",
                    "Post_Caption":"Test",
                    "User_Id":"1"
                 }],
                 "likedetails":[{
                    "Post_Id":"1",
                    "LikeCount":"345"
                 }],
                 "commentdetails":[
                    {
                       "Comments":"testA",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testB",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testC",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testD",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testE",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "User_Id":2,
           "Username":"te",
           "Records":[
              {
                 "Profile":[{
                    "User_Id":"2",
                    "UserImage":"",
                    "Fullname":"Test",
                    "Username":"te"
                 }],
                 "Post":[{
                    "Post_Id":"2",
                    "UploadFile":"",
                    "Post_Caption":"Test",
                    "User_Id":"2"
                 }],
                 "likedetails":[{
                    "Post_Id":"12",
                    "LikeCount":"3452"
                 }],
                 "commentdetails":[
                    {
                       "Comments":"testA",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testB",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testC",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testD",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testE",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "User_Id":3,
           "Username":"te",
           "Records":[
              {
                 "Profile":[{
                    "User_Id":"3",
                    "UserImage":"",
                    "Fullname":"Test3",
                    "Username":"te3"
                 }],
                 "Post":[{
                    "Post_Id":"3",
                    "UploadFile":"",
                    "Post_Caption":"Test",
                    "User_Id":"3"
                 }],
                 "likedetails":[{
                    "Post_Id":"3",
                    "LikeCount":"345"
                 }],
                 "commentdetails":[
                    {
                       "Comments":"testA",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testB",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testC",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testD",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testE",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "User_Id":4,
           "Username":"te",
           "Records":[
              {
                 "Profile":[{
                    "User_Id":"4",
                    "UserImage":"",
                    "Fullname":"Test4",
                    "Username":"te4"
                 }],
                 "Post":[{
                    "Post_Id":"4",
                    "UploadFile":"",
                    "Post_Caption":"Test4",
                    "User_Id":"4"
                 }],
                 "likedetails":[{
                    "Post_Id":"4",
                    "LikeCount":"3454"
                 }],
                 "commentdetails":[
                    {
                       "Comments":"testA",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testB",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testC",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testD",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testE",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "User_Id":5,
           "Username":"te",
           "Records":[
              {
                 "Profile":[{
                    "User_Id":"5",
                    "UserImage":"",
                    "Fullname":"Test5",
                    "Username":"te5"
                 }],
                 "Post":[{
                    "Post_Id":"5",
                    "UploadFile":"",
                    "Post_Caption":"Test5",
                    "User_Id":"5"
                 }],
                 "likedetails":[{
                    "Post_Id":"5",
                    "LikeCount":"3455"
                 }],
                 "commentdetails":[
                    {
                       "Comments":"testA",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testB",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testC",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testD",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testE",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  }
var follow ={
         "AllFollow":[
            {
               "Records":[
                  {
                     "Followdetails":[
                        {
                           "User_Id":"1",
                           "UserImage":"",
                           "Fullname":"Test1",
                           "Username":"te1"
                        },
                        {
                           "User_Id":"2",
                           "UserImage":"",
                           "Fullname":"Test2",
                           "Username":"te2"
                        },
                        {
                           "User_Id":"3",
                           "UserImage":"",
                           "Fullname":"Test3",
                           "Username":"te3"
                        },
                        {
                           "User_Id":"4",
                           "UserImage":"",
                           "Fullname":"Test4",
                           "Username":"te4"
                        },
                        {
                           "User_Id":"5",
                           "UserImage":"",
                           "Fullname":"Test5",
                           "Username":"te5"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }



 let btn_class = this.state.likebutton ? "spriteheartempty" : "spriteheartfill";
  let btn_savclass = this.state.savebutton ? "spritesave" : "spritesaved";
  let mypost=this.state.mypost;
  let arr=[];

    let $imagePreview = (<div className="previewText image-container">Please select an Image for Preview</div>);

    if (this.state.imagePreviewUrl) {
        $imagePreview = ( <div className="image-container" style={{ marginTop: '5px',padding: '5px'}} ><img src={this.state.imagePreviewUrl} alt="icon" width="200" /> </div>)
    }

return (

   <div id="react-root">

   <Helmet>
      <meta charSet="utf-8" />
       <title>Dashboard • Instagram</title>
       <link rel="icon" href="/insta.ico" />

   </Helmet>
        <section className="post_section_flex post_section">
        <Header/>
           <div></div>
           <main className="post_main post_main1" role="main">               
              <section className="post_section_left_flex post_section_left">
              {
              Json.AllPost.map((user) => {

                 {
                    if(user.Records!=undefined)
                    {
                     user.Records.map(record =>{
                       return  (
                       <div className="post_section_outer">
                    <div>
                       <div style= {{flexdirection: 'column', paddingbottom: '6553px', paddingtop: '0px'}}>
                          <article className="_8Rm4L M9sTE  L_LMM SgTZ1   ePUX4">
                          { 

                          record.Post.map(post =>{
                          return ( 
                              <header className="post_section_header_flex post_section_header ">
                                <div className="post_section_header_icon_flex post_section_header_icon" role="button" tabIndex="0">
                                   <canvas className="cnvas" height="42" width="42" style={{position: 'absolute', top: '-5px',  left: '-5px', width: '42px', height: '42px'}}></canvas>
                                   <span className="post_section_header_span " role="link" tabIndex="0" style={{width: '32px',  height: '32px'}}>
                                   <img alt="followindiancricket's profile picture"             className="post_section_header_image" src="https://scontent-maa2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/72440940_1149583128547207_8378383594128670720_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-maa2-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_ohc=SLnG-HyjbUsAX-gpA24&amp;oh=70276049b5204ca4361b9af8e5609e03&amp;oe=5ED53A34"/>
                                   </span>
                                </div>
                                <div className="post_section_header_content_flex post_section_header_content">
                                   <div className="post_section_header_content1">
                                      <div className="post_section_header_content2">
                                         <h2 className="post_section_header_content3">
                                            <a href="/follow" className="post_section_header_a_flex post_section_header_a">
                                           {user.Username}
                                            Test</a>
                                         </h2>
                                      </div>
                                   </div>
                                </div>
                             </header>
                           );
                     })

                   } 
                             <div className="">
                                <div className="post_section_body_outer" role="button" tabIndex="0">
                                   <div className="post_section_body_outer1">

                                         <div className="post_section_body_outer2" style={{paddingbottom: '56.1333%'}}>
                                            <img alt="" className="post_section_body_img" decoding="auto" sizes="614px" style={{objectfit: 'cover'}} src="https://scontent-maa2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/83308853_1028085250883216_7625513747424223693_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-maa2-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=108&amp;_nc_ohc=c5a_p6bAp4EAX9N8U0L&amp;oh=039d39990a00df5addab5426a98c4ad7&amp;oe=5ECC6722" />
                                         </div>
                                         <div className="post_section_body_outer3"></div>

                                      </div>
                                   </div>
                             </div>
                                <div className="post_section_comment">

                                   <section className="post_section_comment_like_count_val_flex post_section_comment_like_count_val">
                                      <div className="post_section_comment_like_count_flex_outer">
                                         <button className="post_section_comment_like_count_flex post_section_comment_like_count1" type="button"  onClick={this.togglePoplike}>
                                         <span>{this.state.count}</span> likes
                                         </button>
                                         {this.state.showlikePopup ? <Popuplike toggle={this.togglePoplike} /> : null}
                                      </div>
                                   </section>
                                   <div className="      Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm           XfCBB ">
                                   { 

                          record.Post.map(post =>{
                                    return  (
                                       <div className="     Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm   pjcA_   ">
                                         <div className="          QzzMF         Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_   vwCYk   ">
                          <a className="FPmhX notranslate MBL3Z" href="">
                             {user.Username}
                             Follow</a>
                                            <span>
                          <span>
                             {post.Post_Caption}
                          Test</span>
                                            </span>
                                         </div>
                                      </div>
                                    );
                                  })
                               }
                               {
                                  record.commentdetails.forEach(comment => {                                     
                                   return ( 
                                   <div>
                                         <div className="   Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm   pjcA_   ">
                                            <a className="r8ZrO" href =""></a>
                                         </div>
                                         <div className="     Igw0E   rBNOH        eGOV_     ybXk5    _4EzTm   pjcA_  ">
                                            <div className=" QzzMF         Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_        vwCYk   ">
                                  <a className="FPmhX notranslate MBL3Z" href="">
                                     {comment.Username}
                                     Follow</a>
                                               <span>
                                  <span>
                                     {comment.Comments}
                                  Test</span>
                                               </span>
                                            </div>
                                         </div>
                                      </div>
                                    );
                                  })
                                  } 

                                   </div>
                                   <section className="post_section_comment_text_outer">
                                      <div>
                                         <form className="post_section_comment_text_form" >
                                            <textarea aria-label="Add a comment…" placeholder="Add a comment…" className="post_section_comment_text_box" autoComplete="off" onChange={this.onChangeComment} autoCorrect="off" value={this.state.Comment} style={{height: '18px'}}></textarea>
                                            <button className="sqdOP yWX7d    y3zKF     " type="submit" disabled={!this.state.Comment}>Post</button>
                                         </form>
                                      </div>
                                   </section>
                                </div>
                                <div className="post_section_header_button">
                                   <button className="post_section_header_button_flex" type="button" onClick={this.togglePop}>
                                   {this.state.seen ? <Popup toggle={this.togglePop} /> : null}
                                      <div className="post_section_header_button_flex1" style={{height: '24px', width: '24px'}}>
                                         <svg aria-label="More options" className="_8-yf5 " fill="#262626" height="16" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="16">
                                            <circle clipRule="evenodd" cx="8" cy="24" fillRule="evenodd" r="4.5"></circle>
                                            <circle clipRule="evenodd" cx="24" cy="24" fillRule="evenodd" r="4.5"></circle>
                                            <circle clipRule="evenodd" cx="40" cy="24" fillRule="evenodd" r="4.5"></circle>
                                         </svg>
                                      </div>
                                   </button>
                                </div>
                          </article>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                       );
                    })
                   }
                 } })}  
                    <div className="post_section_space">
                    </div>
                    <div className="post_section_right">
                       <div className="post_section_right_top">
                          <div className="post_section_right_top1">
                             <div className="post_section_right_button" role="button" tabIndex="0">
                                <canvas className="CfWVH" height="60" width="60" style={{position: 'absolute', top: '-5px', left: '-5px', width: '60px', height: '60px'}}></canvas>
                                <a className="_2dbep qNELH kIKUG" href="/profile" style={{width: '50px', height: '50px'}}><img alt=" profile picture" className="_6q-tv" src="https://scontent-maa2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13551647_1103951302984701_819335256_a.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-maa2-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_ohc=kNncCEMGknkAX8E7LX5&amp;oh=d114e3d1b4374efab3aa4f8686ad3ebe&amp;oe=5EC67023"/></a>
                             </div>
                             <div className="post_section_right_prof">
                                <div className="post_section_right_prof1">
                                   <a className="post_section_right_lin" href="/profile"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div className="post_section_right_name">
                                </div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                       <div className="post_section_right_suggest_flex post_section_right_suggest_outer">
                       <span style={{padding: '5px', textAlign: 'center'}}><h1>Post File</h1></span><br></br>
                       <div className="post_section_right_suggest_flex1 post_section_right_suggest_outer1">
                               <form>
                                  <input   ref="file"   type="file"   name="user[image]" onChange={this.fileChangedHandler}     style={{padding: '5px', marginLeft: '31px'}} />
                                  {$imagePreview}
                                  <textarea className="p7vTm" id="pepBio" placeholder="Enter Text here" value={this.state.Comment} onChange={this.onChangeComment}></textarea>
                                  <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{this.state.errors["Comment"]}</span>
                                  <div className="signin_form_button">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Upload" onClick={this.Submit} className="signin_form_buttonstyle" />
                                    </div>
                               </form>
                       </div>
                       </div>

                          })
                          })
                          } 
                       </div>
                    </div>

              </section>
           </main>
        </section>
        <Footer/>
     </div>
    )
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

[image]

Comment: Is it you full code? i can't see import for Helmet, Header, Footer and Popup

Comment: check that code pen url for full code: https://codepen.io/dotnet345/pen/oNXBxBM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
{Json.AllPost.map(user => {
                return (

                  user.Records != undefined?
                    user.Records.map(record => {
                      return (
                        <div className="post_section_outer">
                          <div>
                            <div
                              style={{
                                flexdirection: "column",
                                paddingbottom: "6553px",
                                paddingtop: "0px"
                              }}
                            >
                              <article className="_8Rm4L M9sTE  L_LMM SgTZ1   ePUX4">
                                {record.Post.map(post => {
                                  return (
                                    <header className="post_section_header_flex post_section_header ">
                                      <div
                                        className="post_section_header_icon_flex post_section_header_icon"
                                        role="button"
                                        tabIndex="0"
                                      >
                                        <canvas
                                          className="cnvas"
                                          height="42"
                                          width="42"
                                          style={{
                                            position: "absolute",
                                            top: "-5px",
                                            left: "-5px",
                                            width: "42px",
                                            height: "42px"
                                          }}
                                        />
                                        <span
                                          className="post_section_header_span "
                                          role="link"
                                          tabIndex="0"
                                          style={{
                                            width: "32px",
                                            height: "32px"
                                          }}
                                        >
                                          <img
                                            alt="followindiancricket's profile picture"
                                            className="post_section_header_image"
                                            src="https://scontent-maa2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/72440940_1149583128547207_8378383594128670720_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-maa2-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_ohc=SLnG-HyjbUsAX-gpA24&amp;oh=70276049b5204ca4361b9af8e5609e03&amp;oe=5ED53A34"
                                          />
                                        </span>
                                      </div>
                                      <div className="post_section_header_content_flex post_section_header_content">
                                        <div className="post_section_header_content1">
                                          <div className="post_section_header_content2">
                                            <h2 className="post_section_header_content3">
                                              <a
                                                href="/follow"
                                                className="post_section_header_a_flex post_section_header_a"
                                              >
                                                {user.Username}
                                                Test
                                              </a>
                                            </h2>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </header>
                                  );
                                })}
                                <div className="">
                                  <div
                                    className="post_section_body_outer"
                                    role="button"
                                    tabIndex="0"
                                  >
                                    <div className="post_section_body_outer1">
                                      <div
                                        className="post_section_body_outer2"
                                        style={{ paddingbottom: "56.1333%" }}
                                      >
                                        <img
                                          alt=""
                                          className="post_section_body_img"
                                          decoding="auto"
                                          sizes="614px"
                                          style={{ objectfit: "cover" }}
                                          src="https://scontent-maa2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/83308853_1028085250883216_7625513747424223693_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-maa2-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=108&amp;_nc_ohc=c5a_p6bAp4EAX9N8U0L&amp;oh=039d39990a00df5addab5426a98c4ad7&amp;oe=5ECC6722"
                                        />
                                      </div>
                                      <div className="post_section_body_outer3" />
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="post_section_comment">
                                  <section className="post_section_comment_icon post_section_comment_val">
                                    <span className="post_section_comment_span">
                                      <button
                                        style={{
                                          alignitems: "center",
                                          border: "0"
                                        }}
                                        className={btn_class}
                                        type="button"
                                        onClick={this.changeColor}
                                      />
                                    </span>
                                    <span className="post_section_comment_span1">
                                      <button
                                        className="post_section_comment_button_like"
                                        type="button"
                                        onClick={this.viewPost}
                                      >
                                        <svg
                                          aria-label="Comment"
                                          className="_8-yf5 "
                                          fill="#262626"
                                          height="24"
                                          viewBox="0 0 48 48"
                                          width="24"
                                        >
                                          <path
                                            clipRule="evenodd"
                                            d="M47.5 46.1l-2.8-11c1.8-3.3 2.8-7.1 2.8-11.1C47.5 11 37 .5 24 .5S.5 11 .5 24 11 47.5 24 47.5c4 0 7.8-1 11.1-2.8l11 2.8c.8.2 1.6-.6 1.4-1.4zm-3-22.1c0 4-1 7-2.6 10-.2.4-.3.9-.2 1.4l2.1 8.4-8.3-2.1c-.5-.1-1-.1-1.4.2-1.8 1-5.2 2.6-10 2.6-11.4 0-20.6-9.2-20.6-20.5S12.7 3.5 24 3.5 44.5 12.7 44.5 24z"
                                            fillRule="evenodd"
                                          />
                                        </svg>
                                      </button>
                                    </span>
                                    <button
                                      className="post_section_comment_button_like"
                                      type="button"
                                    >
                                      <svg
                                        aria-label="Share Post"
                                        className="_8-yf5 "
                                        fill="#262626"
                                        height="24"
                                        viewBox="0 0 48 48"
                                        width="24"
                                      >
                                        <path d="M46.5 3.5h-45C.6 3.5.2 4.6.8 5.2l16 15.8 5.5 22.8c.2.9 1.4 1 1.8.3L47.4 5c.4-.7-.1-1.5-.9-1.5zm-40.1 3h33.5L19.1 18c-.4.2-.9.1-1.2-.2L6.4 6.5zm17.7 31.8l-4-16.6c-.1-.4.1-.9.5-1.1L41.5 9 24.1 38.3z" />
                                        <path d="M14.7 48.4l2.9-.7" />
                                      </svg>
                                    </button>
                                    <span className="post_section_comment_save">
                                      <button
                                        className="post_section_comment_button_like"
                                        type="button"
                                        style={{
                                          alignitems: "center",
                                          border: "0"
                                        }}
                                        className={btn_savclass}
                                        onClick={this.changeColorsave}
                                      />
                                    </span>
                                  </section>
                                  <section className="post_section_comment_like_count_val_flex post_section_comment_like_count_val">
                                    <div className="post_section_comment_like_count_flex_outer">
                                      <button
                                        className="post_section_comment_like_count_flex post_section_comment_like_count1"
                                        type="button"
                                        onClick={this.togglePoplike}
                                      >
                                        <span>{this.state.count}</span> likes
                                      </button>
                                      {this.state.showlikePopup ? (
                                        <Popuplike
                                          toggle={this.togglePoplike}
                                        />
                                      ) : null}
                                    </div>
                                  </section>
                                  <div className="      Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm           XfCBB ">
                                    {record.Post.map(post => {
                                      return (
                                        <div className="     Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm   pjcA_   ">
                                          <div className="          QzzMF         Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_   vwCYk   ">
                                            <a
                                              className="FPmhX notranslate MBL3Z"
                                              href=""
                                            >
                                              {user.Username}
                                              Follow
                                            </a>
                                            <span>
                                              <span>
                                                {post.Post_Caption}
                                                Test
                                              </span>
                                            </span>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      );
                                    })}
                                    {record.commentdetails.forEach(comment => {
                                      return (
                                        <div>
                                          <div className="   Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm   pjcA_   ">
                                            <a className="r8ZrO" href="" />
                                          </div>
                                          <div className="     Igw0E   rBNOH        eGOV_     ybXk5    _4EzTm   pjcA_  ">
                                            <div className=" QzzMF         Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_        vwCYk   ">
                                              <a
                                                className="FPmhX notranslate MBL3Z"
                                                href=""
                                              >
                                                {comment.Username}
                                                Follow
                                              </a>
                                              <span>
                                                <span>
                                                  {comment.Comments}
                                                  Test
                                                </span>
                                              </span>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      );
                                    })}
                                  </div>
                                  <section className="post_section_comment_text_outer">
                                    <div>
                                      <form className="post_section_comment_text_form">
                                        <textarea
                                          aria-label="Add a comment…"
                                          placeholder="Add a comment…"
                                          className="post_section_comment_text_box"
                                          autoComplete="off"
                                          onChange={this.onChangeComment}
                                          autoCorrect="off"
                                          value={this.state.Comment}
                                          style={{ height: "18px" }}
                                        />
                                        <button
                                          className="sqdOP yWX7d    y3zKF     "
                                          type="submit"
                                          disabled={!this.state.Comment}
                                        >
                                          Post
                                        </button>
                                      </form>
                                    </div>
                                  </section>
                                </div>
                                <div className="post_section_header_button">
                                  <button
                                    className="post_section_header_button_flex"
                                    type="button"
                                    onClick={this.togglePop}
                                  >
                                    {this.state.seen ? (
                                      <Popup toggle={this.togglePop} />
                                    ) : null}
                                    <div
                                      className="post_section_header_button_flex1"
                                      style={{ height: "24px", width: "24px" }}
                                    >
                                      <svg
                                        aria-label="More options"
                                        className="_8-yf5 "
                                        fill="#262626"
                                        height="16"
                                        viewBox="0 0 48 48"
                                        width="16"
                                      >
                                        <circle
                                          clipRule="evenodd"
                                          cx="8"
                                          cy="24"
                                          fillRule="evenodd"
                                          r="4.5"
                                        />
                                        <circle
                                          clipRule="evenodd"
                                          cx="24"
                                          cy="24"
                                          fillRule="evenodd"
                                          r="4.5"
                                        />
                                        <circle
                                          clipRule="evenodd"
                                          cx="40"
                                          cy="24"
                                          fillRule="evenodd"
                                          r="4.5"
                                        />
                                      </svg>
                                    </div>
                                  </button>
                                </div>
                              </article>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      );
                    })
                  :null
                )
              })}
```

**the problem was in first map ,you are not returning anything ,i modified the if condition to a ternary**

Answer (score 0):

According your code you have

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {
}

 render() {   var Json={
```

You create class component and immediately closed it
so you render function is not a part of component

Could you try move render inside {}

also you should remove one closed div, as there are problem with closed tags

```
  </div>
                    </div> --- THIS ONE
                 {/* </div> */}
              </section>
           </main>
        </section>
```

Comment: create a code sandbox of as ,it has more than 400 lines of code and share it in your question

Comment: Are you able to see any error in console?

Read it one more time, and inside render you use state, but you do not have it declaration in code, also $imagePreview

Comment: still problem with closed div tag
also you have `records: records`, but records is not defined